# Suggestions on designing the sound of an animated skeleton?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

For an animation project I am doing the sound design for a stop motion animation, where there features a animated dog skeleton. I'm curious as to how one would go about try to designing the sounds of it's movements? I'm considering just knocking bones together and pitching it down. Any other approach?

Comment: Is it meant to be scary or funny? This isn't really my area, but I think it matters.

Comment: It's meant to be scary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot design this independent from the animation.  What keeps the bones together?  A creaky sound (lack of synovial fluid) will obviously be accompanied by small jerks in the execution of the movement.  Are the bones kept together by magic?  More likely than not you'll get smooth movement with rustling noises where bones scratch over the ground and occasional clanks when bones strike each other.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's the latter so I'll be trying that out

Answer (score 1):

Try plastic parts such as toy keys attached to a ring. This sounds boney, especially with a quick, small dog.